# PHP email form broken

Tags: php, html, email

I'm having issues with my code below. Can anyone tell me why my email form below is not working anymore. I've looked at the code a dozen of times. It worked for the longest time and now all of a sudden I'm not getting any emails. I got nothing in my inbox/spam folder.

Any feedback is welcome! Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="php/send.php">
  <input style="color:black" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
  <input style="color:black" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input style="color:black" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone Number">
  <input style="color:black" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  <textarea  style="color:black" name="comments" placeholder="Message/Comments"></textarea>
<p class="return-msg"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Message">
</form>
```

**PHP: send.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "myemaill@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Form";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

<h2>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</h2>

<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs, check your mail logs. Stop suppressing errors using @. Etc etc.

Comment: What debugging have you done?  What exactly does "not working" mean?  What _is_ happening?

Comment: For one thing, `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {...}` is redundant; you're already checking to see if it's not set later on.

Comment: @JonStirling thanks for the reply. I see no error logs on both

Comment: @PatrickQ checking error logs, my code (a dozen of times) haha ;)

Comment: Simply looking at your code over and over is not debugging.